# Wie übersetzt man 'Oh, a fellow Swiss'?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

"Oh, ein Schweizer" sagt, dass der andere ein Schweizer ist, aber nicht dass man selber einer ist. Gibts solch eine Formulierung?

"Ich bin auch Schweizer" ist eine Möglichkeit, hat den Fokus allerdings auf 'ich' und nicht auf dem anderen.

Comment: Wie wäre es mit einer Neuschöpfung? "Oh, ein Mitschweizer!" :-)

Comment: Hm, informal würd ich das sogar so verwenden.

Comment: Freue mich schon drauf, es mal zu hören :-) Generell sollten Schweizer aber doch keine Probleme haben, einander zu erkennen, oder? Ein herzhaftes **Grüezi** und der Drops ist gelutscht :-) Das macht aber die allgemeine Frage nicht weniger relevant!

Comment: @Jan stell als Frage rein, das gefällt mir bis jetzt am besten ;-)

Comment: ich hoffe, ich habe jetzt den aus Deiner Sicht richtigen meiner beiden Kommentare zur Antwort gemacht ;-)

Comment: @Jan war der falsche ^^

Comment: ...und schon korrigiert :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich schlage eine Neuschöpfung vor:

> "Oh, ein Mitschweizer!"

Comment: ...auf Bitten von @Tass als Antwort hinzugefügt :-)

Answer (score 10):

Ein üblicher Ausdruck, der früher häufig verwendet wurde:

> Oh, ein Landsmann / eine Landsfrau!

Die Aussage bedeutet, dass die angesprochene Person dieselbe Nationalität wie die Person, die spricht, besitzt.

Sie auch: [Wiktionary-Eintrag zu Landsmann](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Landsmann)

Comment: I think I'm understanding from your explanation that the expression has fallen out of use to the extent that it now calls for explanation even among native German speakers? Interestingly many languages have the identical expression, especially when the speakers feel themselves to be part of a distinct group immersed in a larger culture. I doubt, for example, that the Italian "paesano" means as much in Italy as it does in America. My wife's people, the Chiu Chao minority, proudly identify each other as "ka ki nang". Of course "landsmann" is very much a Yiddish expression.

Comment: @MartyGreen I think it'll still be understood (still present in most people's passive vocabulary), but is rarely said anymore (i.e. not in the active vocabulary). It also being a Yiddish expression is a testament to the shared roots of these languages :-)

Comment: @Marty Green I agree with Jan. People will still understand it and I'm sure there are people who are using it.

Comment: @splattne: I once heard my (Austrian) godmother use the word "Landsleute." Is that countryMEN (plural)?

Comment: @Tom Au: you're absolutely right. That's the correct plural form.

Comment: I don't think this word is outdated (at least not in Germany). I use it frequently in holidays abroad. Germans are just everywhere ;)

Answer (score 6):

> Ah, auch ein Eidgenosse!

Schweizerische Eidgenossenschaft ist der offizielle deutsche Name der Schweiz

Comment: Eher `Ah, ein Eidgenosse!`, aber ohne das `auch` ist die Information nicht drinnen, dass man selber einer ist, und mit klingts holprig :-(

Comment: stimmt man kann da mit Füllwörtern arbeiten wie gut schön etc...

Comment: @Tass enthält ´-genosse´ nicht implizit, dass man selber auch dazugehört?

Answer (score 3):

Wie wäre es mit:

«Oh, auch Sie sind Schweizer?» oder

«Oh, Sie sind auch Schweizer?».